# Maximum call stack size exceeded select2

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting this error on select2

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.extend.n.fn.extend (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Here's my code:

```
success: function (data) 
{
     newdata = JSON.parse(data);
     result  = newdata.record;

     $("#edit_group_users option:selected").each(function () 
     {
          $(this).removeAttr('selected');
     });

     if (result != '') 
     {
          for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
          {
              $('#edit_user' + result[i].contact_id).prop('selected', true);

              $('#edit_group_users').select2();
          }
      }
}
```

When i remove this line

```
$('#edit_group_users').select2();
```

i am getting no error but select2 not work, i am using multiple select2 here's my html code

```
<select class="select2 form-control select2-multiple" 
id="edit_group_users" multiple="multiple" name="contacts[]">

<?php foreach($contact_list as $contact): ?>
<option id="edit_user<?= $contact->id; ?>" value="<?= $contact->id; ? >"> 
<?= $contact->full_name; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Given that there *has* to be only 1 `#edit_group_users` element in the DOM, why are you instantiating Select2 on it in a loop?

Comment: i try to use it out of loop but it stills wont work

Comment: currently i am using two functions $('#view_group_users').select2(); this one select2 for viewing and this one inside $('#edit_group_users').select2(); edit

Comment: I don't believe that issue is related to the error, as that generally means you're you're somehow creating infinite recursion. Given the limited code example, we can't really see why that is, though.